# UI IsDirty versus Entity IsDirty

Tags: wpf, binding, save

I am well aware of the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged for WPF binding.  This has been implemented and is working as expected.  Therefore, changes to a property on our entities will set their "IsDirty" flag.  Which in turn, turns on the Save functionality, all via binding, beautiful you may say.

However, we recently had a change request raised to request that the Save button should become enabled as soon as the field changes (i.e. use presses the first keystroke), much like the **undo** application command does when you type in a textbox.  Therefore the save button must know when every field is changed on the form instead of the property being changed in the entity via binding.

The main reason for this request for help, is one of our forms only has one field that changes (everything else normally remains default), but the user still has to tab out of the field to enable the Save button, instead of just being able to save straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) to `PropertyChanged`

This will update the binding everytime the text changes rather than `LostFocus` - which is the default for a textbox.

```
<TextBlock Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```